# office-ui-fabric-react Interface 'ITooltipProps' incorrectly extends interface 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement | TooltipBase>

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

I am using node version 14.17.6 and react version 19 with fluientui/react. Here is my dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
        "@fluentui/react": "^7.202.0",
        "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.0.0-rc1",
        "react-scripts-ts": "^3.1.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
        "typescript": "3.4.5"
    },
```

But when run npm run build it is giving error:
Interface 'ITooltipProps' incorrectly extends interface 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement | TooltipBase>'.
Types of property 'content' are incompatible.
Type 'string | Element | Element[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.